# How to substitute 2 columns values in dataframe with their ids from other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a df_value:

```
metric_type metric_name   metric_value  
visits      total         111
visits      time_related  222
followers   total         333
followers   time_related  444
```

and another df with ids for the metric_type and metric_name

```
df_ids

metric_id  metric_name   metric_type 
1          total         visits
2          time_related  visits
3          total         followers   
4          time_related  followers
```

I need to change values like this:

```
metric_id   metric_value    
1           111
2           222
3           333
4           444
```

I have tried to combine metric_name with metric_type in one column in both dfs:

```
df_value['combined']=df_value.apply(lambda x:'%s_%s' % (x['metric_name'],x['metric_type']),axis=1)
df_ids['combined']=df_ids.apply(lambda x:'%s_%s' % (x['metric_name'],x['metric_type']),axis=1)
```

and tried to change values like this

```
df_value.rename(
                columns=dict(zip(df_ids['combined'], df_ids['metric_id'])))
```

But it doesn't work, I have no idea how to proceed. Appreciate any help

Comment: are these actual values, where 1 -> 111 2 ->222 ... 9 -> 999

Comment: it could be any values, 1-> 15653 and so on

Comment: Could you manually write your desired output?

Comment: put it already I need to change values like this:

Comment: `df_value.merge(df_ids, on=['metric_name', 'metric_type'])`?

Comment: @ Code Different, haaa, so simple and I forgot totally, appreciate thanks, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
# Dataframes:
data1 = [
    ['visits', 'total', 111],
    ['visits', 'time_related', 222],
    ['followers', 'total', 333],
    ['followers', 'time_related', 444]
]
cols_1 = ['metric_type', 'metric_name', 'metric_value']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=cols_1)

data2 = [
    [1, 'total', 'visits'],
    [2, 'time_related', 'visits'],
    [3, 'total', 'followers'],
    [4, 'time_related', 'followers']
]
cols_2 = ['metric_id', 'metric_name', 'metric_type']

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=cols_2)

# Solution:
pd.merge(
    df1, df2, on=['metric_type', 'metric_name']
)[['metric_id', 'metric_value']]
```

Output:

```
  metric_id   metric_value
0   1         111
1   2         222
2   3         333
3   4         444
```

Answer (score 2):

This should worked:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [df_ids['metric_id'], df_value['metric_value']]).transpose()
```

Output:

```
   metric_id  metric_value
0          1           111
1          2           222
2          3           333
3          4           444
```